# How add context menu item to Windows Explorer which takes me to some specific location in the same instance of explorer.exe

Tags: windows, registry, contextmenu, explorer

I want to add a context menu item in windows explorer which takes me to some desired location, I searched the internet but the results i got created a new instance of the explorer.I want to know if there is some way which does it in the same instance of the explorer.exe.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? You want Explorer to navigate to folder you want when you click your new menu item?

Comment: Yes you are right, I want to do it in the same instance of the explorer.

Comment: Don`t know how it can be done with registry but there is a way if you create ContextMenu shell extension. Do you need details?

Answer (score 0):

**1:** First, launch regedit.exe from the Start menu.

**2:** Expand the *HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT* key.

**3:** Expand the *Directory* key.

**4:** Expand the *Background* key.

**5:** Expand the *shell* key.

**6:** Right-click the shell key and create a new key. Name the key what you want the option to appear as in the menu. I named it "customcommand".

**7:** Right-click the key you just created and create a new subkey under it. Name the new key “command.”

**8:** Double-click the “(Default)” value in the command key and paste this in the value:

```
C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe /root,C:\Windows
```

**9:** Press the OK button.

**10:** Now if you right-click on desktop or on any other folder, you will see "customcommand" in the context menu. When you click this newly created menu, a new folder view will open and show C:\Windows. You can change the target path which you saw in 8th step.

**Further info:**

http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/152457/windows-explorer-command-line-options

Comment: Well it's add the application shortcut in the context menu, what i have to do is to go to some folder location from that context menu item.

Comment: Just examine the article and work with explorer.exe under "Windows" folder. You will need to add the path parameter. Look at here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/152457/windows-explorer-command-line-options

Comment: I've updated my answer. I tested it on my local and it works fine.

Comment: Well it does that but it creates the new instance of the explorer.exe, you can check that in the task manager that as you click the new menu item in the context menu it creates the new instance of explorer.exe. As I said I want to do it in the same instance of the explorer.exe